# MFMailComposeViewController displaying only bar

Tags: iphone

MFMailComposeViewController displaying only bar at the top of the screen with the cancel and send buttons. Code for landscape:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:@"In app email..."];
[controller setMessageBody:@"...Hi, all...." isHTML:NO];
//[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,320);
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
[controller release];
```

What is problem?

Answer (score 0):

i've ever seen this problem before, as far as i know, you shouldn't replace the presentModalViewController method with addsubview.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this behavior, as well as the modal view coming in from the side and the modal view was stopping a quarter of the way through presenting.

In my app I had many view controllers stacked with addSubview:.  I don't know why but it worked to present the modal view from the bottom view controller.  I did something like this:

```
[((FirstViewController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).firstViewControllerInstance sendEmailwithInfo];
```

Hope that helps!  And maybe someone can give some insite as to why it was happening.